# ETRADE - Get Request Token using ColdFusion

Tags: oauth, coldfusion

I'm attempting to get a Token from ETrade to start the authentication process, but I can't seem to get the signature to match what eTrade thinks it should be.

The Link to the ETrade API:
https://developer.etrade.com/ctnt/dev-portal/getDetail?contentUri=V0_Documentation-AuthorizationAPI-GetRequestToken

The Link to the OAuth Spec:
https://oauth.net/core/1.0a/#sig_base_example

I've had to scrample the consumer key and secret for obvious reasons so this code can't be tested directly... but the issue seems to be that the parameters that I send over don't match the hash that I'm sending.

The response I receive back from Etrade is: oauth_problem=signature_invalid.  I've seen a number of libraries, I'm open to attempting one of those but none seem to match up with Etrade's approach.  All thoughts welcome!  Thanks in advance.

```
<!--- Generate epoctime --->
<cfset TheDate = now()>
<cfset TheDate = DateAdd("h",5,TheDate)>
<cfset EpocTime = DateDiff("s", "January 1 1970 00:00", DateConvert("local2utc", TheDate))>

<!--- Set Keys / URL --->
<cfset consumer_key = "aaaaaaaaa">
<cfset consumer_secret = "1111111">
<cfset GetTokenURL = "https://etws.etrade.com/oauth/request_token">

<!--- generate message for oauth signature --->
<cfset message = "GET">
<cfset message = message & "&" & "https%3A%2F%2Fetws.etrade.com%2Foauth%2Frequest_token">
<cfset message = message & "&" & "oauth_callback%3Doob">
<cfset message = message & "%26oauth_consumer_key%3D#consumer_key#">
<cfset message = message & "%26oauth_nonce%3DLTg2ODUzOTQ5MTEzMTY3MzQwMzE%3D">
<cfset message = message & "%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1">
<cfset message = message & "%26oauth_timestamp%3D#epoctime#">

<!--- debug message --->
<cfoutput>#message#</cfoutput><BR><BR>

<!--- Apply HMAC function to generate signature (absent of token) --->
<cfset oauth_signature = hmac(message, consumer_secret & "&", "HMACSHA1")> 
<cfoutput>#oauth_signature#</cfoutput><BR><BR>

<!--- Encode and debug output --->
<cfset oauth_signature = urlencodedformat(toBase64(Binarydecode(oauth_signature , "hex")))>
<cfoutput>#oauth_signature#</cfoutput><BR><BR>

<!--- Make the CFHTTP Request --->
<cfhttp result="result" method="GET" charset="utf-8" url="https://etws.etrade.com/oauth/request_token">
    <cfhttpparam name="Authorization" type="header" value="OAuth" />        
    <cfhttpparam name="realm" type="url" value="">
    <cfhttpparam name="oauth_callback" type="url" value="oob">
    <cfhttpparam name="oauth_consumer_key" type="url" value=#consumer_key#>
    <cfhttpparam name="oauth_nonce" type="url" value="LTg2ODUzOTQ5MTEzMTY3MzQwMzE%3D">
    <cfhttpparam name="oauth_signature" type="url" value=#oauth_signature#>
    <cfhttpparam name="oauth_signature_method" type="url" value="HMAC-SHA1">
    <cfhttpparam name="oauth_timestamp" type="url" value="#epoctime#">  
</cfhttp>

<!--- Output the results --->
<cfoutput>#result.FileContent#</cfoutput>
<BR><BR>
<cfdump var="#result#">
```

Comment: Have you tried their java SDK? In theory, it should just be a matter of [loading a few jars](https://developer.etrade.com/ctnt/dev-portal/getContent?contentUri=V0_Code-SDKGuides-Java) and then converting the [sample code](https://developer.etrade.com/ctnt/dev-portal/getContent?contentUri=V0_Code-Tutorial), which should be very similar in cfscript. Try testing the "Obtain a request token" example first.

Comment: Great suggestion Leigh.  I've imported the .jar files and started translating the Java code examples: public IOAuthClient client = null; becomes <cfset client = CreateObject("java","com.etrade.etws.oauth.sdk.client.IOAuthClient") /> but I'm getting stuck at client = OAuthClientImpl.getInstance(); // Instantiate IOAUthClient ... any ideas?